# What is a Correct Connection String for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What is a correct connection string for SQL Server? The ODBC connection string I used doesn't work. How can I find out what the problem is?

this is small part of entire project I am working on and it is not working.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string constr = "Driver={SQL Server};server=127.0.0.1;uid=test;pwd=test123;database=account";
    //public static string constr = "Driver={SQL Server};server=127.0.0.1;uid=test;pwd=test123;app=Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010;wsid=WIN-8VW8RV959F2;database=account";
    public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
```

Comment: Why you tagged it with C?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Comment: my bad lol, didn't noticed

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819818/sql-server-connection-string)

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string can be rewritten as:

```
data source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=account; user id=test;password=test123
```

Other variations can be found on http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string constr = "Data Source=ServeName;Initial Catalog=Database_Name";
    //public static string constr = "Data Source=ServeName;Initial Catalog=Database_Name";
    public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
```